# AFNetworking downloading and setting images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, afnetworking

I saw two different methods for downloading image from URL:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage"]];
```

and

```
AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:...
```

Which one should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

The first method is built around `UIImageView` (as a category) and allows to download and display images as they are. Usually this method can be useful in table views or other similar interfaces that contains `UIImageView`s. First you will see (if set) a placeholder. When the image is completely downloaded, the placeholder, will be replaced with the real image.

The second method, instead, is useful if you need to download an image and perform some processing. Using completion block, you can verify when the image has been downloaded and do scale, etc.

The most important thing is that while the first method performs an association with the image view and the relative image, in the second case you need to do it your own. Anyway, the second is more flexible since you have a direct control over the image and, so, perform, additional calculations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe @mattt would be say something else on it. ;)

Comment: Tnx on answer, but saw today this method also : 'setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:' Is this some kind of mix of both methods from my question ? Thanks.

Comment: @user1832330 sorry for the delay. What do you need to achieve? That method is the same as the second one but with callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage"]];
```

i use this one in my project and its work fine for me.

Comment: i am also try lazzytableview concept which is the best way tell me if you want more help...

Comment: looks like setImageWithURL is using actually AFImageRequestOperation function so thats probably right for use